# Vectorizing index selection in Numpy 4D array using array of indexes

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I'm having trouble doing the following without a for loop:

I have an array A such that:

```
A.shape = [50,80,100,100]
```

And an array B such that:

```
B.shape = [50,5]
```

and for k, B[k] are the indexes along axis=1 of A that I want to keep ( 0<= B[k,i] < 79)

I want to end up with C such that:

```
C.shape = [50,5,100,100]
```

I can do it with:

```
for k in range(A.shape[0]):
    C[k] = A[k][B[k]]
```

but I didn't find a vectorized way to express that. Since this is run many times : is there a better (faster) way of getting C ?

Comment: Simply use : `A[np.arange(A.shape[0])[:,None],B]`.

Comment: Is `k` the first axis? That usually is `axis=0`.